# How to change colour when user wants another colour in the app?

Tags: java, android

Hi i made an android app and i was thinking, how to implement on a click of a button it changes the whole app to another colour like from white to black. Is there a way that could be possible or am i just up for the impossible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No you can change theme programmatically, its not impossible. `setTheme()` will help you.

First of all create several themes in your `styles.xml`

Then in your button click : `setTheme(R.style.AnotherTheme);`

Additionally you can combine this with `SharedPreferences` to remember latest theme selection at every app opening .