# Two textviews with different colors using one theme?

Tags: android, textview, android-theme

I'm new to android and I have been trying to find out an answer to this. I have a layout file .xml for `listview` that has two textviews, one is for heading with a greater size and other below is for description. What I want is that heading textview's text stays white and description textview's text stays grey in my current theme. That is dark theme. But user has the option to change the theme, so when user selects Light theme I want my heading textview's text (that is within layout that I have for listview's rows) to become black and also the description textview's text to become black.
Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change theme programmatically. There is one guy asked this hours ago. Can you check this: [how-to-change-colour-when-user-wants-another-colour-in-the-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824863/how-to-change-colour-when-user-wants-another-colour-in-the-app/37825182#37825182)

Also if you want to use diferent themes for different `TextViews` you can try like :

```
textView.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
```

> How can i create custom themes for TextViews

in your `styles.xml` create different styles :

```
<style name="MyBlueTextTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"> 
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item> 
    <item name="android:textColor">#123456</item> 
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Then use it like :

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textBlue"
   android:text="This is a blue styled text" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   style="@style/MyBlueTextTheme" />
```

Or use it like: `textView.setTextAppearance(context,R.style.MyBlueTextTheme);`

but its deprecated and you can use `textView.setTextAppearance(R.style.MyBlueTextTheme);` but this can be used `Api23` or higher

Comment: Okay thanks. I actually got my thing done from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the text color programmatically using the method textView.setTextColor(int color), or via XML using the attribute android:textColor="#yourhexcolor"

Comment: Isnt there a way you could define 2 themes for example one light and one dark, and further specify some attributes that do the thing of keeping larger text white and smaller grey and so on.

Comment: how the user switch the theme in your app?

Comment: Main activity contains a navdrawer , where he clicks an item and a contextual menu opens and he selects the theme.